# Eigenvalue argument of polar decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Given an invertible matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and its polar decomposition
$$
A = U H,
$$
where $U$ is unitary, and $H$ is positive definite. I'm interested in the distance of
$$
arg ( \lambda_A ) - arg( \lambda_U )
$$
where $arg ( \lambda_A ) $ denotes the arguement (phase) of the eigenvalues of $A$ in an appropriate order. For normal matrices it is that $arg ( \lambda_A ) - arg( \lambda_U ) = 0$.

Is there a way to estimate the angular difference for non-normal matrices?

Comment: Do you mean angle of _eigenvectors_?

Comment: @emma No, sorry I meant the argument (phase) of the eigenvalues. I will correct this.